# Syslog-ng not sending messages to localhost port 514 on centos 7.5

Tags: centos, syslog, tcpdump

```
tcpdump -nnAs0 -i eth0 port 514
```

As I understand it this should display any logging msgs sent to syslog locally. However I send many via python syslog module, which I can tail via /var/log/messages but do not show up when listening to port 514.

I want to send to this port, how do I do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the messages are appearing in the logs, they are being sent and received by `syslog`.

The problem with your command is that the machine to communicate with itself does use the loopback interface.

So, you are listening to the wrong address in your `tcpdump`.

To see the packets of the communication with `syslog` do:

```
sudo tcpdump -nnAs0 -i lo port 514
```